# Pass reactive value from server to two conditional panels(not nested) in ui in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements, shiny-reactivity

I'm making a shiny app, which takes "dateRangeInput" as input and plots plot for data within that "date range". Also, I'm using `conditionalPanel` to not show the plot when the dates from input are not available in data and show text to the user to select dates only available in data.

The problem is, the conditional panel is not working and not showing anyting at all irrespective of date inputs. (setting the limits to max and min dates available in data to `max` & `min` of `dateRangeInput` is not an option.).

link to data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=17ipXwRimovR_QBYT2O1kxSGTzem_bN-1

Here's what I've done and tried:

```
# loading the data and making the interpretation of first column proper
wait_data <- transform(read.csv("dummy wait times data of 12 departments.csv", header = TRUE),
                       Date = as.Date(Date, "%d-%m-%y"))

# sorting the data according to dates
wait_data <- data.frame(with(wait_data, wait_data[order(Date),]), 
                        row.names = NULL)



library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui_function <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 3,
      dateRangeInput(inputId = 'date_range',
                     label = paste('Choose range from January 1, 2017 to December 31, 2018:'),
                     start = as.Date("2017-01-01"), end = as.Date("2017-05-31"),
                     min = as.Date("2017-01-01"), max = Sys.Date(),
                     separator = " to ", format = "MM-dd, yyyy",
                     startview = 'year', weekstart = 1),
      selectInput(inputId = "department_input", 
                  label = "Choose a Department to see wait times:",
                  choices = c("General Checkup"="General Checkup", 
                              "Emergency"="Emergency",
                              "Cardiology"="Cardiology",
                              "Gynaecology"="Gynaecology",
                              "Maternity"="Maternity",
                              "Neurology"="Neurology",
                              "Oncology"="Oncology",
                              "Orthopedics"="Orthopedics",
                              "Otalaryntology"="Otalaryntology",
                              "Psychiatry"="Psychiatry",
                              "Radiology"="Radiology",
                              "Urology"="Urology"),
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  selected = c("Cardiology","Gynaecology"))
    ),
    mainPanel(width = 9,
      uiOutput("plots_or_text")
      # uiOutput("resource_or_moretext")
      # conditionalPanel(
      #   condition = "output.dates_matches",
      #   plotlyOutput("wait_times_plot"),
      #   dataTableOutput("resource_counts")
      # ),
      # conditionalPanel(
      #  condition = "output.dates_matches",
      #   htmlOutput("select_available_dates")
      # )

      )
    )
  )


server_function <- function(input, output) {

  min_date_in_data <- reactive({min(wait_data[,"Date"])})
  max_date_in_data <- reactive({max(wait_data[,"Date"])})


  # output$dates_matches <- reactive ({
  #   if (input$date_range[2] > max_date_in_data() | input$date_range[1] < min_date_in_data()){return(FALSE)}
  #   else if (input$date_range[2] <= max_date_in_data() | input$date_range[1] >= min_date_in_data()){return(TRUE)}
  #   })
  # 
  # 
  # # output$select_good_dates <- renderText({dates_matches()})
  # output$select_available_dates <- renderText({paste("select dates available in data")})


  # now filter based on date range inputs
  date_range_data <- reactive({
    wait_data[(wait_data[,"Date"] > input$date_range[1] & wait_data[,"Date"] < input$date_range[2]), ]
  })


  # now take the data returned from above aggregation and filter it for department selection.
  filtered_department_data <- reactive({date_range_data()[date_range_data()[,"Department"] %in% input$department_input, ]})


  # # plot it now
  # output$wait_times_plot <- renderPlotly({
  #   plot_ly(data = filtered_department_data(),
  #           x = ~Date, y=~average_wait_time_min,
  #           split = ~Department,
  #           type = "scatter", mode="lines+markers")
  # })



  output$plots_or_text <- renderUI({

    if (input$date_range[2] <= max_date_in_data() | input$date_range[1] >= min_date_in_data()){
        renderPlotly({plot_ly(data = filtered_department_data(),
                              x = ~Date, y=~average_wait_time_min, split = ~Department,
                              type = "scatter", mode="lines+markers")
          })
      }
    else if (input$date_range[2] > max_date_in_data() | input$date_range[1] < min_date_in_data()){
      renderText({paste("select dates available in data")})
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui_function, server_function)
```

That code returns
`object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` in my `mainPanel`.

---

EDIT 1:
changes in server:

```
make_plot <- reactive({
# I've copied the below condition from my if
validate(
     need(input$date_range[2] <= max_date_in_data() | input$date_range[1] >= min_date_in_data(),
          message = "Seems like you've selected dates out of range. Please change your filters."))

    plot_ly(data = filtered_department_data(),
            x = ~Date, y=~average_wait_time_min, split = ~Department,
            type = "scatter", mode="lines+markers")
    # ggplot(data = filtered_department_data(),
    #        aes(x = Date, y=average_wait_time_min, split = Department)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
  })

  output$plot_or_error <- renderPlotly(make_plot())
  # output$plot_or_error <- renderPlot(make_plot())
```

I just can't solve this. both libraries' plots show up irrespective of inputs in `dateRangeInput`. if the data for the selected date range is not available, there's simply a blank plot, no error messages shows up in that case.

Comment: `conditionalPanel` works with elements in the UI. For example, an action button 'show more' opens a box showing more and both the action button and the box are defined in `ui`. But in your app, the decision to plot vs. send error message happens based on filtering in the `server`, and `ui` does not know any values in the `server`, only those explicitly sent to it via `output$`. So you want to create the appropriate element through `renderUI` and send it to the `ui` through `output$name`, while in the `ui` you have `uiOutput("name")`.

Comment: `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`, that's my error for above changes in code after your suggestions.

Comment: please, check the edit in my question now, @teofil

Comment: Its hard to debug since we don't have your entire code or data. But a simpler and better solution is to use `validate`. See my answer for example code which can be easily applied to your app without `renderUI` or `conditionalPanel`.

Comment: check the question now. It has complete code and link to the complete data.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all you want to do is print an informative message when the plot can't be made for some reason, `validate` + `need` are your friends. For example:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- basicPage(
  selectInput(
    inputId = "sp",
    label = "Select species",
    choices = unique(iris$Species),
    #selected = unique(iris$Species),
    multiple = TRUE
  ),
  tags$br(),
  plotOutput("plot_or_error")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  make_plot <- reactive({
    df <- filter(iris, Species %in% input$sp)
    validate(need(nrow(df) > 0, 
    message = "Seems like after filtering there are 0 rows. Please change your filters."))

    ggplot(df, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot() 
  })

  output$plot_or_error <- renderPlot({
    make_plot()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT: r user's code and data.**

```
# loading the data and making the interpretation of first column proper
wait_data <-
  transform(
    read.csv("dummy wait times data of 12 departments.csv", header = TRUE),
    Date = as.Date(Date, "%d-%m-%y")
  )

# sorting the data according to dates
wait_data <- data.frame(with(wait_data, wait_data[order(Date), ]),row.names = NULL)


library(shiny)
library(dplyr) # not necessary, code included with dplyr or base R
library(plotly)

ui_function <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                 dateRangeInput(inputId = 'date_range',
                                label = paste('Choose range from January 1, 2017 to December 31, 2018:'),
                                start = as.Date("2017-01-01"), end = as.Date("2017-05-31"),
                                min = as.Date("2017-01-01"), max = Sys.Date(),
                                separator = " to ", format = "MM-dd, yyyy",
                                startview = 'year', weekstart = 1),
                 selectInput(inputId = "department_input", 
                             label = "Choose a Department to see wait times:",
                             choices = c("General Checkup"="General Checkup", 
                                         "Emergency"="Emergency",
                                         "Cardiology"="Cardiology",
                                         "Gynaecology"="Gynaecology",
                                         "Maternity"="Maternity",
                                         "Neurology"="Neurology",
                                         "Oncology"="Oncology",
                                         "Orthopedics"="Orthopedics",
                                         "Otalaryntology"="Otalaryntology",
                                         "Psychiatry"="Psychiatry",
                                         "Radiology"="Radiology",
                                         "Urology"="Urology"),
                             multiple = TRUE,
                             selected = c("Cardiology","Gynaecology"))
    ),
    mainPanel(width = 9,
              plotlyOutput("plot_or_error")
    )
  )
)


server_function <- function(input, output) {


  make_df <- reactive({
    wait_data %>% 
      filter(Department %in% input$department_input) %>% 
      filter(Date >= input$date_range[1], Date <= input$date_range[2])
  })

  # no dplyr
  make_df_base <- reactive({
    fd <- wait_data[wait_data$Department %in% input$department_input, ]
    fd <- fd[fd$Date > input$date_range[1] & fd$Date < input$date_range[2], ]
    fd

  })

  make_plot <- reactive({
    validate(
      need(nrow(make_df_base()) > 0, # can be make_df()
           message = "Seems like you've selected dates out of range. Please change your filters."))

    plot_ly(data = make_df_base(), # can be make_df()
            x = ~Date, y=~average_wait_time_min, split = ~Department,
            type = "scatter", mode="lines+markers")
  })

  output$plot_or_error <- renderPlotly({make_plot()})

}

shinyApp(ui_function, server_function)
```

**EDIT 2: check with the dates instead of data frame**

```
# loading the data and making the interpretation of first column proper
wait_data <-
  transform(
    read.csv("dummy wait times data of 12 departments.csv", header = TRUE),
    Date = as.Date(Date, "%d-%m-%y")
  )

# sorting the data according to dates
wait_data <- data.frame(with(wait_data, wait_data[order(Date), ]),row.names = NULL)


library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

ui_function <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                 dateRangeInput(inputId = 'date_range',
                                label = paste('Choose range from January 1, 2017 to December 31, 2018:'),
                                start = as.Date("2017-01-01"), end = as.Date("2017-05-31"),
                                min = as.Date("2017-01-01"), max = Sys.Date(),
                                separator = " to ", format = "MM-dd, yyyy",
                                startview = 'year', weekstart = 1),
                 selectInput(inputId = "department_input", 
                             label = "Choose a Department to see wait times:",
                             choices = c("General Checkup"="General Checkup", 
                                         "Emergency"="Emergency",
                                         "Cardiology"="Cardiology",
                                         "Gynaecology"="Gynaecology",
                                         "Maternity"="Maternity",
                                         "Neurology"="Neurology",
                                         "Oncology"="Oncology",
                                         "Orthopedics"="Orthopedics",
                                         "Otalaryntology"="Otalaryntology",
                                         "Psychiatry"="Psychiatry",
                                         "Radiology"="Radiology",
                                         "Urology"="Urology"),
                             multiple = TRUE,
                             selected = c("Cardiology","Gynaecology"))
    ),
    mainPanel(width = 9,
              plotlyOutput("plot_or_error")
    )
  )
)


server_function <- function(input, output) {
  # these don't need to be reactive unless you have the user load or switch datasets
  min_date_in_data <- reactive({ min(wait_data[,"Date"], na.rm = TRUE) })
  max_date_in_data <- reactive({ max(wait_data[,"Date"], na.rm = TRUE) })

  make_df <- reactive({
    se <- input$date_range

    validate(need(se[1] >= min_date_in_data(), message = "The first date is outside the range of the data."))
    validate(need(se[2] <= max_date_in_data(), message = "The second date is outside the range of the data."))
    validate(need(se[1] < se[2], message = "The second date needs to be after the first date."))
    validate(need(input$department_input != "", message = "Please select a department."))

    wait_data %>% 
      filter(Department %in% input$department_input) %>% 
      filter(Date >= input$date_range[1], Date <= input$date_range[2])
  })

  # no dplyr
  make_df_base <- reactive({
    fd <- wait_data[wait_data$Department %in% input$department_input, ]
    fd <- fd[fd$Date > input$date_range[1] & fd$Date < input$date_range[2], ]
    fd

  })

  make_plot <- reactive({

    plot_ly(data = make_df(),
            x = ~Date, y=~average_wait_time_min, split = ~Department,
            type = "scatter", mode="lines+markers")
  })

  output$plot_or_error <- renderPlotly({make_plot()})

}

shinyApp(ui_function, server_function)
```

Comment: I've tried using `validate` and `need` by your suggestion and updated the question with what I've tried. But, couldn't solve it.

Comment: 1. that works only if the both the dates are not available. It's actually when dataframe is empty, message shows up.
2. the conditional check is not for dates.
seems like I can't solve this ever. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Have a look at my new edit. The reasons your date comparisons were failing was because your test data contains `NA` and in such cases `min` and `max` will return `NA` unless you include `na.rm=TRUE`.